# Allow certain part of a page to be easily updated for client?

Tags: custom-post-types, dashboard

My client has asked me to create an about me section which will include a picture, job title and description for each team member as floated elements. They also want it to be as easily updateable as adding a post to a blog. So if they wanted to add a new team member within the same page, they will want to upload the image and enter text into the job title and description box and click publish. Then the new member will appear next to the existing ones.

As a newbie to WP, how would I go about achieving this? I've heard of custom post types but I can't find any tutorials on displaying data in one page.

Any tutorial links or advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this WpTuts+ article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/a-guide-to-wordpress-custom-post-types-creation-display-and-meta-boxes/) about Custom Post Types for you. This is an article that will explain what exactly Custom Post Types are and how to accomplish creating one. This will help you along.

Also, I found [this wpbeginner article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/) about creating custom archive pages. You can use this article to create the custom page wich will show each team member.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike! Just what I needed. It will definity come in handy and I knew it had something to do with custom post types :) thanks again!